# Keras loaded model output is different from the training model output

Tags: neural-network, keras, reshape, multi-output

When I train my model it has a two-dimension output - it is (none, 1) - corresponding to the time series I'm trying to predict. But whenever I load the saved model in order to make predictions, it has a three-dimensional output - (none, 40, 1) - where 40 corresponds to the n_steps required to fit the conv1D network. What is wrong?

Here is the code:

```
df = np.load('Principal.npy')


    # Conv1D
#model = load_model('ModeloConv1D.h5')
model = autoencoder_conv1D((2, 20, 17), n_steps=40)

model.load_weights('weights_35067.hdf5')

# summarize model.
model.summary()

    # load dataset
df = df


    # split into input (X) and output (Y) variables
X = f.separar_interface(df, n_steps=40)
# THE X INPUT SHAPE (59891, 17) length and attributes, respectively ##    

# conv1D input format
X = X.reshape(X.shape[0], 2, 20, X.shape[2])

# Make predictions    

test_predictions = model.predict(X)
## test_predictions.shape =  (59891, 40, 1)

test_predictions = model.predict(X).flatten()
##test_predictions.shape = (2395640, 1)


plt.figure(3) 
plt.plot(test_predictions)
plt.legend('Prediction')
plt.show()
```

In the plot below you can see that it is plotting the input format. 
[image]

Here is the network architecture:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
time_distributed_70 (TimeDis (None, 1, 31, 24)         4104      
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_71 (TimeDis (None, 1, 4, 24)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_72 (TimeDis (None, 1, 4, 48)          9264      
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_73 (TimeDis (None, 1, 1, 48)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_74 (TimeDis (None, 1, 1, 64)          12352     
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_75 (TimeDis (None, 1, 1, 64)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_76 (TimeDis (None, 1, 64)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_17 (LSTM)               (None, 100)               66000     
_________________________________________________________________
repeat_vector_9 (RepeatVecto (None, 40, 100)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_18 (LSTM)               (None, 40, 100)           80400     
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_77 (TimeDis (None, 40, 1024)          103424    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_9 (Dropout)          (None, 40, 1024)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_18 (Dense)             (None, 40, 1)             1025      
=================================================================
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to the output format. Instead of outputting one value per input sequence, in order to produce a complete and unique sequence as output, it was outputting sequences. Though instead of having a unique sequence as result it got a sequence of sequences. The solution was to fix the network output shape and data shape as well.